# How to integrate GMetrics tool with grails 3x application

Tags: java, grails, groovy

Actually i need to integrate GMetrics static code analysis tool with grails 3x application but i'm not able to do it.

Please help me out if somebody already did it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need the following snippets in your build.gradle file

```
configurations {
    gmetrics
}
dependencies {
    ...
    gmetrics 'org.gmetrics:GMetrics:0.7'
}
task gmetrics {
    doLast {
        //use GMetrics ant task - http://gmetrics.sourceforge.net/gmetrics-ant-task.html
        ant.taskdef(name: 'gmetrics', classname: 'org.gmetrics.ant.GMetricsTask', classpath: configurations.gmetrics.asPath)
        //ensure reporting directory created
        ant.mkdir(dir: "${project.reporting.baseDir.path}/gmetrics")
        ant.gmetrics() {
            report(type: 'org.gmetrics.report.BasicHtmlReportWriter') {
                option(name: 'outputFile', value: "${project.reporting.baseDir.path}/gmetrics/gmetrics.html")
            }
            report(type: 'org.gmetrics.report.XmlReportWriter') {
                option(name: 'outputFile', value: "${project.reporting.baseDir.path}/gmetrics/gmetrics.xml")
            }
            fileset(dir: 'src') {
                include(name: '**/*.groovy')
                //exclusions to filter out any classes with inner classes - sonar doesn't support
                exclude(name: '**/*Config*')
            }
            fileset(dir: 'grails-app') {
                include(name: '**/*.groovy')
                //exclusions to filter out any classes with inner classes - sonar doesn't support
                exclude(name: '**/*Config*')
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can invoke the *gmetrics* task, and find the report in *build/reports/gmetrics/*

Comment: not working getting error  ` gmetrics 'org.gmetrics:GMetrics:0.7'`

Comment: You must have the configurations closure above the dependencies closure. Otherwise you might get that error